# SSIS Conditional Split flat file rows

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm looking to add an SSIS package to split a flat file with multiple rows to multiple files based on each row.

[image: See image here]

The file contains the data like this:

TH|166777|20130930110716|2|Till 1|Customer Support|002|Manchester|-99.00|-82.50|-16.50|0.00|0.00|0.00|-99.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|till|sold|9|2-1007-9999||Balding|Claire|Ms| Customer |Ashby Road|Loughborough|Leicestershire|LE11 3NG|GBR|01509 232200||||||||||||||||||
TO|4SA671:MULTI:10|5252525000026|Andrea Shirt|COLOUR: Multi / COLOUR: Multi-pack / SIZE: 10. / |1|0.00|-82.50|

110.00|-99.00|0.00|20.00|1|0.00|refund|n/a||WTOP||0|0|0.00||0.00|486|1666|485||GOOD Goodwill
TT|card|-99.00|GBP||Visa Credit |||
TF|3|1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SUBSTRING([Column 0],1,2) == "TH"
```

Comment: Thank you but I actually fixed it, by using:  [Column 0]=="TH" and it pulled the row as I wanted it.